# why does post request have parameters in twitter api?

Tags: rest, http, post

I am new to restful web development. I saw in twitter api Post request (https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/direct_messages/new)
the parameters are passed in the url

> https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status=Maybe%20he%27ll%20finally%20find%20his%20keys.%20%23peterfalk

Is it OK to specify query parameters in case of post in the url itself. When we do post programatically we specify the post data separately in the request body. Also, in terms of rest web design, is this the correct way to pass query parameters using post.